# how to separate alternating digits and characters in string into dict or list?

Tags: python, dictionary, pointers

'L134e2t1C1o1d1e1'

the original string is "LeetCode"

but I need to separate strings from digits, digits can be not only single-digit but also 3-4 digits numbers like 345.

My code needs to separate into dict of key values; keys are characters and numbers is the digit right after the character. Also create 2 lists of separate digits, letters only.

expected output:

```
letters = ['L', 'e', 't', 'C', 'o', 'd', 'e']
digits = [134,2,1,1,1,1,1]
```

This code  is not properly processing this.

```
def f(s):

    d = dict()
    letters = list()
    # letters = list(filter(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), s))

    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        print('----------------------')
        if not s[i].isdigit():

            letters.append(s[i])

        else:
            j = i
            temp = ''
            while j < len(s) and s[j].isdigit():
                j += 1

            substr = s[i:j]
            print(substr)
            
        i += 1

    print('----END -')
    print(letters)
```

Comment: `L981e276t1C1o1d331e15657` has 2 `e`, `dict` keys are unique, what should be value for `e`?

Comment: oh sorry, it should be  "L1e2t1C1o1d1e1" - the number of times the char repeats

Comment: Shouldn't `i` be set to `j` after the inner while loop terminates (after the assignment to `substr`)? And also you should'nt increment `i` in that case.

Comment: @qouify, i m confused, idk.

Comment: OP can you show us the expected output? I can't tell exactly what you want.

Comment: Can you post the expected result for your example? You're expecting a dict with letter as key and value as list of digits for that letter?

Comment: @user56700, sorry my bad, i updated the main post

Comment: Is that a LwwtCode problem? Which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You edited your question and I got a bit confused, so here is a really exhaustive code giving you a list of letters, list of the numbers, the dict with the number associated with the number, and finally the sentence with corresponding number of characters ...

```
def f(s):
    letters = [c for c in s if c.isalpha()]
    numbers = [c for c in s if c.isdigit()]

    mydict = {}
    currentKey = ""
    for c in s:
        print(c)
        if c.isalpha():
            mydict[c] = [] if c not in mydict.keys() else mydict[c]
            currentKey = c
        elif c.isdigit():
            mydict[currentKey].append(c)

    sentence = ""
    for i in range(len(letters)):
        count = int(numbers[i])
        while count > 0:
            sentence += letters[i]
            count -= 1

    print(letters)
    print(numbers)
    print(mydict)
    print(sentence)
```

Comment: This does not generate the required output and yet has been accepted as the most appropriate answer

Comment: @LancelotduLac The required output has been added after this answer was posted, I believe the code is self explanatory and easy enough to be modified for the slight difference but the author. It worked perfecly when the input was `f('L1e2t1C1o1d1e1')`

Answer (score 2):

With the following modification your function separates letters from digits in `s`:

```py
def f(s):
    letters = list()
    digits = list()
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        if not s[i].isdigit():
            letters.append(s[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            j = i
            temp = ''
            while j < len(s) and s[j].isdigit():
                j += 1
            substr = s[i:j]
            i = j
            digits.append(substr)
    print(letters)
    print(digits)
f('L134e2t1C1o1d1e1')
```

As said in my comments you didn't update `i` after the inner loop terminates which made `i` go back to a previous and already processed index.

Answer (score 2):

If I would be limited to not use regex I would do it following way

```
text = 'L134e2t1C1o1d1e1'
letters = [i for i in text if i.isalpha()]
digits = ''.join(i if i.isdigit() else ' ' for i in text).split()
print(letters)
print(digits)
```

output

```
['L', 'e', 't', 'C', 'o', 'd', 'e']
['134', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

Explanation: for letters I use simple list comprehension with condition, `.isalpha()` is str method which check if string (in this consisting of one character) is alphabetic. For digits (which should be rather called numbers) I replace non-digits using single space, turn that into string using `''.join` then use `.split()` (it does split on one or more whitespaces). Note that `digits` is now `list` of `str`s rather than `int`s, if that is desired add following line:

```
digits = list(map(int,digits))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string only had two `e's`, so I've added one more to complete the example. This is one way you could do it:

```
import re

t = 'L1e34e2t1C1o1d1e1'
print(re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', '', t))
```

Result:

`LeetCode`

I know you cannot use regex, but to complete this answer, I'll just add a solution:

```
def f(s):
    d = re.findall('[0-9]+', s)
    l = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]', s)
    print(d)
    print(l)

f(t)
```

Result:

```
['134', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
['L', 'e', 't', 'C', 'o', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: i can't use regex, ideally i just want to parse the string into separate numbers /letters lists

Answer (score 0):

```
letters = []
digits = []
dig = ""
for letter in 'L134e2t1C1o1d1e1':
    if letter.isalpha():
        # do not add empty string to list
        if dig:
            # append dig to list of digits
            digits.append(dig)
            dig = ""
        letters.append(letter)
        # if it is a actual letter continue
        continue
    # add digits to `dig`
    dig = dig + letter
```

Try this. The idea is to skip all actual letters and add the digits to `dig`.

Answer (score 0):

I know there's an accepted answer but I'll throw this one in anyway:

```
letters = []
digits = []

lc = 'L134e2t1C1o1d1e1'
n = None
for c in lc:
    if c.isalpha():
        if n is not None:
            digits.append(n)
            n = None
        letters.append(c)
    else:
        if n is None:
            n = int(c)
        else:
            n *= 10
            n += int(c)
if n is not None:
    digits.append(n)

for k, v in zip(letters, digits):
    dct.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
print(letters)
print(digits)
print(dct)
```

**Output:**

```
['L', 'e', 't', 'C', 'o', 'd', 'e']
[134, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
{'L': [134], 'e': [2, 1], 't': [1], 'C': [1], 'o': [1], 'd': [1]}
```